# Angular / Keen-Slider: Slider just work in modal when resize window

Tags: angular, slider, window-resize

I'm creating a carousel using keen-slider in Angular and as long as I use it directly on the page it works fine, but if I use it inside a modal it destroys. It only works again if I resize the browser window.

[image]

And when we do the resize it works fine:

[image]

What do you think must be happening?

Comment: A quick look at the keen-slider source shows that it calculates some of its sizing via scripting. Most likely, the keen-slider code is executed before the angular parent element has calculated its width, resulting in your slider being collapsed until you trigger a recalculate, such as when the window is resized.

Comment: I made a minimal Stackblitz verifying the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qvra56?file=src/app/modal/modal.component.ts Your problem is as suspected. The keen-slider tries to grab the width of the parent container before angular has finished updating the content in the DOM, resulting in a small width. You must manually trigger update on your slider when your content is ready. How you'd do so varies depending on what modal you are using.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen You are amazing. Thank you very much for your help, if you want you can send your contribution as an answer so I can give it as correct, I have been able to solve my problem.

Comment: I don't want to add it as an answer since the minimal approach in my investigation has a couple of problems. Chief among those being the mechanism for detecting when the content is ready for triggering an update.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty method would be to simply trigger a window resize event in the modal dialog's ngOnInit method (or another [lifecycle event](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence)):

```js
export class MyDialog implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  }
}
```

I've sometimes had to resort to using a setTimeout in bizarre situations, but  don't tell anyone.