# Other Solutions for Applying Dynamic Slides in Keen Slider Only When Resizing the Window

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, swiper.js

I'm using Vue 3 and the Quasar framework to create a dynamic carousel. Every time I switch to the next slide, I send an API request to retrieve data for three books, which I then add to the books[] array. I'm using v-for to render the carousel slides using Keen Slider.

I came across a post on Stack Overflow (link: [Angular / Keen-Slider: Slider just work in modal when resize window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71934538/angular-keen-slider-slider-just-work-in-modal-when-resize-window)) where they suggested triggering the resize event (window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));) to make it work. I implemented this approach, and it worked for me. I have set it to resize every second.

However, I encountered another issue. When I add a large number of slides to the books[] array at once, the carousel stops resizing. Strangely, if I manually navigate to the next slide one by one, it works fine.

I'm wondering if there are alternative ways to make the carousel dynamic and handle a large number of slides.

Additionally, I tried using other libraries such as Swiper. Unfortunately, I found that its slideNext function is broken and cannot be used. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduction with dummy data.